# TDBadgeView nsstring crash without ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Using TDBadgeView, been fine until iOS8, now crashes

```
-[__NSArrayI sizeWithFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d989f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sizeWithFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d989f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x23682c1f 0x30e2dc8b 0x23688039 0x23685f57 0x23687208 0x16ca47 0x26b3f4d7 0x26567a0d 0x265633e5 0x2656326d 0x26562c51 0x26562a55 0x2655c92d 0x236493b5 0x23646a73 0x23646e7b 0x23595211 0x23595023 0x2a98e0a9 0x26ba11d1 0xf2a03 0x313adaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Seems to object to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *badgeString;
```

What's changed in ios8 that's making code that's worked since ios5 now crash (project is non-ARC)

edit:
this is this the initialstion call

```
TDBadgedCell *cell = [[[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface TDBadgeView : UIView
{
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger width;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *badgeString;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   UITableViewCell *parent;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIColor *badgeColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIColor *badgeColorHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   BOOL showShadow;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CGFloat radius;

@end

@interface TDBadgedCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *badgeString;
@property (readonly, retain)    TDBadgeView *badge;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIColor *badgeColor;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIColor *badgeColorHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   BOOL showShadow;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TDBadgedCell.h"

@implementation TDBadgeView

@synthesize width=__width, badgeString=__badgeString, parent=__parent, badgeColor=__badgeColor, badgeColorHighlighted=__badgeColorHighlighted, showShadow=__showShadow, radius=__radius;

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat fontsize = 11;

    CGSize numberSize = [self.badgeString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: fontsize]];

    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0 , 0, numberSize.width + 12 , 18);
    CGFloat radius = (__radius)?__radius:4.0;

    UIColor *colour;

    if((__parent.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) && (__parent.highlighted || __parent.selected))
    {
        if (__badgeColorHighlighted)
        {
            colour = __badgeColorHighlighted;
        } else {
            colour = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.000f];
        }
    } else {
        if (__badgeColor)
        {
            colour = __badgeColor;
        } else {
            colour = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.530f green:0.600f blue:0.738f alpha:1.000f];
        }
    }

    // Bounds for thet text label
    bounds.origin.x = (bounds.size.width - numberSize.width) / 2.0f + 0.5f;
    bounds.origin.y += 2;

    CALayer *__badge = [CALayer layer];
    [__badge setFrame:rect];

    CGSize imageSize = __badge.frame.size;

    // Render the image @x2 for retina people
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00)
    {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake(__badge.frame.size.width * 2, __badge.frame.size.height * 2);
        [__badge setFrame:CGRectMake(__badge.frame.origin.x,
                                     __badge.frame.origin.y,
                                     __badge.frame.size.width*2,
                                     __badge.frame.size.height*2)];
        fontsize = (fontsize * 2);
        bounds.origin.x = ((bounds.size.width * 2) - (numberSize.width * 2)) / 2.0f + 1;
        bounds.origin.y += 3;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width * 2;
        radius = radius * 2;
    }

    [__badge setBackgroundColor:[colour CGColor]];
    [__badge setCornerRadius:radius];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [__badge renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

    [__badgeString drawInRect:bounds withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontsize] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);

    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [outputImage drawInRect:rect];

    if((__parent.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) && (__parent.highlighted || __parent.selected) && __showShadow)
    {
        [[self layer] setCornerRadius:radius];
        [[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        [[self layer] setShadowRadius:1.0];
        [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8];
    } else {
        [[self layer] setCornerRadius:radius];
        [[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
        [[self layer] setShadowRadius:0];
        [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:0];
    }

}

- (void) dealloc
{
    __parent = nil;
    [__badgeString release];
    [__badgeColor release];
    [__badgeColorHighlighted release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end


@implementation TDBadgedCell

@synthesize badgeString, badge=__badge, badgeColor, badgeColorHighlighted, showShadow;

#pragma mark - Init methods

- (void)configureSelf
{
    // Initialization code
    __badge = [[TDBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.badge.parent = self;

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.badge];
    [self.badge setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]))
    {
        [self configureSelf];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]))
    {
        [self configureSelf];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Drawing Methods

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(self.badgeString)
    {
        //force badges to hide on edit.
        if(self.editing)
            [self.badge setHidden:YES];
        else
            [self.badge setHidden:NO];


        CGSize badgeSize = [self.badgeString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 11]];
        CGRect badgeframe = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - (badgeSize.width + 25),
                                       (CGFloat)round((self.contentView.frame.size.height - 18) / 2),
                                       badgeSize.width + 13,
                                       18);

        if(self.showShadow)
            [self.badge setShowShadow:YES];
        else
            [self.badge setShowShadow:NO];

        [self.badge setFrame:badgeframe];
        [self.badge setBadgeString:self.badgeString];

        if ((self.textLabel.frame.origin.x + self.textLabel.frame.size.width) >= badgeframe.origin.x)
        {
            CGFloat badgeWidth = self.textLabel.frame.size.width - badgeframe.size.width - 10.0f;

            self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, badgeWidth, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
        }

        if ((self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x + self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width) >= badgeframe.origin.x)
        {
            CGFloat badgeWidth = self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width - badgeframe.size.width - 10.0f;

            self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.x, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y, badgeWidth, self.detailTextLabel.frame.size.height);
        }

        //set badge highlighted colours or use defaults
        if(self.badgeColorHighlighted)
            self.badge.badgeColorHighlighted = self.badgeColorHighlighted;
        else
            self.badge.badgeColorHighlighted = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.000f];

        //set badge colours or impose defaults
        if(self.badgeColor)
            self.badge.badgeColor = self.badgeColor;
        else
            self.badge.badgeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.530f green:0.600f blue:0.738f alpha:1.000f];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.badge setHidden:YES];
    }

}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    [self.badge setNeedsDisplay];

    if(self.showShadow)
    {
        [[[self textLabel] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        [[[self textLabel] layer] setShadowRadius:1];
        [[[self textLabel] layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8];

        [[[self detailTextLabel] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        [[[self detailTextLabel] layer] setShadowRadius:1];
        [[[self detailTextLabel] layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self.badge setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) 
    {
        self.badge.hidden = YES;
        [self.badge setNeedsDisplay];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else 
    {
        self.badge.hidden = NO;
        [self.badge setNeedsDisplay];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [__badge release];
    [badgeColor release];
    [badgeString release];
    [badgeColorHighlighted release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I think your problem is not in this code. The mistake should be in the cellForRow in the tableViewDataSource, you might put a nsarray instead of a nsstring in the badgeString property.

Comment: yes it seems the nsstring is being released, but only in ios8 - why? And why would an nsarray work instead?

Comment: sound strange. Nevertheless is easy to debug the nsstring release. That is: Create your custom NSString (b.e JBString), override only dealloc methods (here you can put a NSLog or breakpoint), in the place where you create a badgeString, create it as a JBString. You can see easily if this object is released. (In this case adding a retain only in iOS 8 before and that's it. But It's really strange than the pointer after be released point to other object (NSArray) when it should  point to nil. I'm still thinking than the mistake is another thing. Good  luck.